# Facebook page rate limit - fetch post with comments and subcomments

Tags: facebook, limit, restfb

I'd like to fetch facebook Post with comments and subcomments (lib: restfb for java)

```
public Post getNewPost(String postId) {
  ...
  String fields = ".... fields ...";
  Post foundPost = facebookClient.fetchObject(postId, Post.class, Parameter.with("appsecret_proof", prof), Parameter.with("fields", fields));
```

And it works great, fetching post and post content. My question is that 'request' costs me api call for each comment and subcomment ??

E.g

1) post -> 2 comments

By fetching this post will I use 1 api call (1 for post & content) or 3 api calls ? (1 for post & 2 for comments).

I know that graph api provide .limit(x) function, but I have to fetch post and any comment from this post with at least N history comments. And it doesn't matter if it is comment or subcomment. So I can't use until / since  and limit functions.

So my 2nd question is there any way to fetch post and all comments and subcomments with only 1 api call or how to minimalize api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer is: it depends. You can not get unlimited amount of comments in one call, so you have to page through the comments.

To get all comments and subcomments you can use the `filter=stream` parameter. With this option all comments and subcomments are returned as plain list in chronological order. See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/comments/

If you only fetch one post with all comments you can fetch the Post (1 call) and then fetch the depending comments (total count comments + subcomments divided by count of elements per page). I'm not sure about the max limit you can get per page but I think it's between 200 and 500. So you can optimize the calls.

BTW you can fetch the comment count with your post and drop requesting the comments if there are none. Or you can fetch with the post the max limit of comments. Then you have to page only if there are more than max limit comments.